# Jackson JSON Mapping "NoClassDefFoundError: JsonPropertyDescription"

Tags: java, json, jar, jackson, noclassdeffounderror

I am using the Jackson jars (core 2.3.1, annotations 2.2.3, databind 2.3.1, all the latest from the downloads page) to read a Json file, grab what I need put it into a new object and write/printout that object to a file or the screen.

I have seen most examples say that it's as easy as

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Or

```
ObjectWriter mapper = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
writer.writeValueAsString(object);
```

**Although I have the necessary jar's I keep getting the error** 
ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyDescription.

Upon digging deeper I find that the `JsonPropertyDescription` class that is in the github for jackson, is *not packaged with the annotations 2.2.3 jar*.

So has it been deprecated and there is some new way I haven't seen to take an object and print it to json, or was this class accidentally left out of the newer version?

Comment: Wait, why do you use -core 2.3.x and -annotations 2.2.x?

Comment: For annotations 2.2x is the latest version. I know its confusing, there was a github issue opened because of this. I guess the annotations jar is meant to be more static so it won't get upgraded as often

Comment: Can you try with -core 2.2.x and see if it works?

Comment: Not easily, as I use 'MappingJsonFactory();` which gives `jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z` error if I just try and switch it out. But even if it worked, why would they release the other jar's if they wern't compatible with the annotations jar. `ObjectMapper` and `ObjectWriter` are actually in the databind jar, they just depend on the annotations jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you've solved this already by updating your jars but here go some answers:

> Upon digging deeper I find that the JsonPropertyDescription class that is in the github for jackson, is not packaged with the annotations 2.2.3 jar.

It's a [new feature in 2.3](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/pull/13#issuecomment-21825260).

> Is there some new way I haven't seen to take an object and print it to json?

I don't think so: [writeValueAsString() 2.3.3](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.3.3/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L2269) (it's not deprecated).

It looks like someone had a [similar problem](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-twitter/issues/8#issuecomment-39363166) and the solution they suggested is basically "update your jars". The asker didn't reply so we don't know whether that worked or not.

Comment: We ended up abandoning Jackson as updating the jars would have had to go through a whole bureaucratic process of approval.